# PHP: Check text with their ids

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have table that I select all items, and display them in a random, so I created an input text to put the ID there, once the person insert the ID, she can check whether that ID corresponds to the text, i.e:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `book`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`vID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Text` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `book`
--

INSERT INTO `book` (`ID`, `vID`, `Text`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Text1'),
(2, 2, 'Text2'),
(3, 3, 'Text3');
```

the query is like this:

```
$aSel = 'SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY RAND()';
```

display is like this:

```
echo '<input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="Num[]">';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo $Text.'<br />;
echo '<input type="submit" name="check">';
```

So once I click on check button, how can I check that the Num value is the same as the vID, my goal is make text in random and then make it in order using vID

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Why would you order by random and then order it by a value? Wouldn't it be simpler to just order by something in the table and then add the order by to your SQL query?

Comment: this is like a test questions, make text in a random, then the user should make it in order

Comment: so can I transfer text data from one page to another?